# What is the class name of dragged KENDO UI grid column header object?

Tags: class, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

*Sorry, that’s somehow a stupid question but I have no clue to find it out:*

When dragging a column (header) at a **KENDO UI grid** (for reordering or grouping by the columns) you get an object attached to the mouse arrow with the name of the column in it.

I would like to style that object with CSS but I have no idea how to find out it’s **class name**.

I can’t locate it in the inspector (since it’s only visible while dragging) and I don’t find anything about it in the Telerik / Kendo documentation.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Sorry, guys. Right after posting it here I’ve found out myself: it is **.k-drag-clue** (so now I have a clue … hmm)

Answer (score 0):

There’s a div with the classes `.k-header` and **`.k-drag-clue`** added to the bottom right before `</body>`:

```
<div class="k-header k-drag-clue" style="…">
    <span class="k-icon k-drag-status k-denied"></span>…
</div>
```